# how to set orientation with in zooz framework in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

i am using `zooz framework`, in which it work perfectly in potrait but when i rotate to landscape then its frame has changed in odd manner.how can i set the zooz view frame??

```
zooz = [ZooZ sharedInstance];
              
[zooz preInitialize:@"e6178b33-fac9-4a41-b296-162a28e291f8" isSandboxEnv:IS_SANDBOX];

// NSLog(@"HIIII");
    
//ZooZ * zooz = [ZooZ sharedInstance];
     
zooz.sandbox = IS_SANDBOX;
    
zooz.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.8 blue:0 alpha:1];
    
zooz.barButtonTintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zooz For iPhone currently do not support landscape and will always be in Portrait. 
iPad does support all orientations.

In order to enable zooz in a landscape iPhone app, you should show zooz from a portrait only view controller

If its only landscape app - you should enable all orientation modes in your target and force the landscape on all your view controllers on the "allowed orientation" methods.

For the view controller that shows the ZooZ ui you should set as portrait
this way your app stays in landscape and the zooz UI is portrait

Answer (score -1):

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: sry it set to landscape..because it work perfectly in portrait.

Comment: You need ans or wanna debate?